# How to Make Windows Phone 7 Panorama Page look like Windows Phone 8 Version

Tags: xaml, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, microsoft-metro, themes

In my application that I have, I would like to make my Windows Phone 7 Panorama page theming, fonts, margins, etc match the Windows Phone 8 version. This is because I have some features that only work in Windows Phone 8, and therefore have two versions of my application, but I would like them to look and feel the exact same. I'm assuming that this would involve creating some sort of Style that matches the Windows Phone 8 version, and applying it to my Windows Phone 7 version, but I do not know how to accomplish this?

Comment: The styling differences between WP7 & WP8 are minor (fonts & margin are the same, for example). You should explain more precisely what you are looking for, maybe with screenshots.

Comment: Essentially create the reverse of http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2013/01/pivot-and-panorama-have-moved-and.html where I can retemplate the header and title (which seems to be the only changes from Windows Phone 7 to Windows Phone 8 if I'm correct.

Answer (score 0):

[Matt Lacey](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1755/matt-lacey) has written a[n excellent blog post](http://blog.mrlacey.co.uk/2013/01/pivot-and-panorama-have-moved-and.html) on this, albeit from the opposite perspective.  You should be able to pull out the styling elements you need to tweak to get your controls looking the way they should.